# Get current class+method name in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging

I wondered if there is a simple way I have have a snippet which traces the name of a method when called. I found `className` which is half-way there, but not something for the method... a 1-line `trace(...)` is what I'm after so I avoid typing the method name and leaving myself open to mistakes.
This is for testing the order things happen, when I don't want to step through in the debugger.

Comment: asked on 2011-1-11-10-11...that's cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have compiled your swf with debug information and use the debug version of the player you can take a look at [getStackTrace](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Error.html#getStackTrace%28%29) property from the [Error](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Error.html) object:

Quick example:

```
    public function getCallingInfos():Object{
        var tmp:Array=new Error().getStackTrace().split("\n");
        tmp=tmp[2].split(" ");
        tmp=tmp[1].split("/");
        return {namespaceAndClass:tmp[0], method:tmp[1]};
    }

    var infos:Object=getCallingInfos();
    trace(infos.namespaceAndClass, infos.method);
```

Comment: What would happen in a release version? Does `trace` disappear, and would your method return nothing, or break?

Comment: this example method is to be used in a debug environment not in a release one, as for the trace it will not dissapear unless you have choose the omit trace option or search for conditional compilation to have code that will be present in debug mode and not in release .

Comment: If you want to still be able to trace errors when things go wrong in the production environment, consider using a Logger class and set the debug level by configuration rather than in the AS code. There is a logging framework in AS3 commons: http://code.google.com/p/as3-commons/ but so far I have written my own simple Logger class and found it quite sufficient.

Comment: @weltraumpirat with a release swf you will not be able to use getStackTrace to have method information since these informations are not included.

Comment: True. Though in some cases, especially when you occasionally need runtime information about a more complex system, it might be worth not excluding the debug information in your compilation settings, but switching trace output on and off by setting a debug level.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static function getCurrentClassName(c:Object):String
    {
        var cString:String = c.toString();
        var cSplittedFirst:Array = cString.split('[object ');
        var cFirstString:String = String(cSplittedFirst[1]);
        var cSplittedLast:Array = cFirstString.split(']');
        var cName:String = cSplittedLast.join('');

        return cName;
    }
```

Used to check if a certain class is constructed or not.

Usage (here I put the code in the main class):

```
trace('[DEBUG]: '+ClassData.getCurrentClassName(this)+' constructed.');
```

trace returns:

```
[DEBUG]: Main constructed.
```

Comment: while it's not necessarily a bad solution, it does rely on the `toString()` function not having being implemented in your class